# How to answer "write something on the board"?

Tags: interviewing, india

Recently I was in an interview and the very first thing I was asked to do was "write something on the board" and I wrote "something" which they said they found rude. They also said "are you a robot to follow orders blindly?". 
I didn't have anything else on my mind so I wrote that.

And it was followed by other questions related to the job.

The interview was for Business Analyst position at a Fintech Company.

Was there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95382/discussion-on-question-by-anal-how-to-answer-write-something-on-the-board).

Comment: Did they ask "are you a robot" etc in response to you writing "something" or was that separate later?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Don't be a smart alec in interviews. You want to present the most professional and friendliest version of yourself.

If there's an unclear question (and if the question actually was just "write something on the board" then that's about as unclear as it gets) you should behave as you would if something unclear came up during your actual job as a business analyst, and ask questions of your own to clarify their expectations.

If you can't get any further details out of them then go with something neutral, such as your name. And frankly at that point I'd mark the job as one to decline any offers from, unless there's something amazing about it, as the interviewers are the ones being rude and unprofessional.

I suspect the point was to see how prospective business analysts would turn something unclear into something clear though. And if that *wasn't* the point then it was a great opportunity to *make it* the point.

Comment: Who knows, maybe it was one of those 'think outside of the box' questions.

Comment: @dwjohnston Can't get anymore outside the box than challenging the question itself. Attempting to clarify the question not only challenges it but does so in a productive manner.

Comment: Frankly, to *not* think that writing "something" on the board would be acceptable would be an insult to the asker's intelligence. You're saying "I think you aren't smart enough to realize that your request is vague".

Comment: Also, "you should behave as you would if something unclear came up during your actual job" goes both ways. If someone not doing what they wanted came up during *their* actual job, would they respond with insults?

Comment: @Acccumulation actually smart alec is the standard spelling in BRE. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/smart-alec

Comment: @PlayerOne I'm guessing the insult Acccumulation is referring to is the interviewer calling them a robot. That "most professional and friendliest version" goes both ways too. If anal wrote a quote from literature would the response have been: "Do you think you can just inject whatever you want into requirements?" -Also: "I didn't have anything else on my mind so I wrote that." anal wasn't being a smart alec, they were not trying to be funny or sarcastic, just a bit literal when put on the spot. Seems to me they just hit a bad interview.

Comment: @Mr.Mindor You're right, that's definitely an insult, and I believe it was exceptionally unprofessional of the interviewer. If that happened to me I would not proceed further in the hiring process with that company. That information was not in the question when I wrote my answer.

Comment: Nope. This answer is terrible. If they ask you to do something you don't understand, you need to first clear that up. If you can't clear it up, then you don't want the job. It's that simple. Imagine going for a job where you make meals and someone said "Can you cough for me?", would you cough? I'd look for a job where they don't interview chefs based on how they cough, I definitely wouldn't cough to be "polite".

Comment: @insidesin I'm not sure I understand your objection. My answer says that the interviewee should clarify what they're being asked to do, and decline the job if the interviewer refuses to...

Comment: Sounds like the OP made a sincere, if sub-optimal, attempt at fulfilling the request. Did not get the sense that the OP was trying to be a smart alec.

Comment: `If you can't get any further details out of them then go with something neutral, such as your name.` This is terrible. The worst thing you can do in an interview is something with no reason.

Comment: @insidesin Fair enough. At that point I would have lost interest in trying to prove myself to the interviewer, so I'd not be to worried about what I wrote as long as it was professional. In my opinion writing something neutral would be professional. I'm not sure why you feel anything would be "terrible" at a point where you also feel the candidate shouldn't want the job any more, but all good.

Comment: If they asked you to dance like a dog, would you dance like a dog *professionally* too?

Comment: The question was a bit unfair though, a customer would never ask for "something", and you hear of many ridiculous interview questions which *do* require you to be a smart-alec which have no bearing on the job ("How many golf balls would fit in this room?", and such)

Comment: @mcknz Even if OP did not *intend* to be a smart alec, that's how they came across during the interview. Just by reading the account I already got a bad impression about OP because they stroke me as 1) cannot recognize unclear instructions that might impact job performance and need to be clarified beforehand, 2) if they did, have a penchant for sarcasm / malicious compliance that can make them obstructive and uncooperative in a team setting. No excuse for the interviewers to be *that* rude, but a good watchout for OP on what can be inferred about them during the interview

Answer (score 87):

> Is there a better way to handle this?

You could have asked them a question or two regarding what they would like you to write.

Asking questions to better understand the requirements is something Business Analysts do a lot.

Perhaps that's what the interviewers were hoping for.

Comment: That's the only logical conclusion I can really come to. Clarifying requirements is a very necessary BA skill to have, and it really doesn't get less clear than the requirement OP was given.

Comment: And in my experience, you often get requirements that are about as dumb as "write something on the board" when under the hood they're incredibly complex and require hours or days of investigation to nail down. This question seems to have performed its intended purpose.

Comment: @corsiKa Unfortunately, you're right.

Answer (score 59):

Given this fact

> Interview was for Business Analyst position at a Fintech Company.

The question "write something on the board" was definitely a **test**, which you **failed**. A BA's entire job is talking to the product owner and trying to determine what the product requirements and specifications are.

From [this university's](https://www.villanovau.com/resources/business-analysis/business-analyst-career/) site (first result for the search "what does a business analyst do") :

> The analyst interacts with the business stakeholders and subject
>   matter experts in order to understand their problems and needs
>
> The analyst gathers, documents, and analyzes business needs and requirements

You were expected to talk to the interviewers to try to decipher what their true requirements were. In your normal day to day, you will frequently be asked to do vague and/or unclear things, which you need to "translate" into product requirements.

Was it a bad, and intentionally confusing, question? *Probably.* But that really isn't the point of this question.

Comment: It was a test and the company failed. Why do people always forget interviewing is a two way process?

Comment: They asked the OP to write something. The OP wrote "something". If they wanted something other than "something", this was then an opportunity for them to say so. Thus, the OP writing "something" on the board *was* directed towards "trying to determine what the product requirements and specifications are". In a real-world situation, you shouldn't spend several months with unclear specifications, but if you can turn in a "project" in a few seconds, then it is completely reasonable to clarify specifications by turning in a project knowing that it likely doesn't do what the client wants.

Comment: See https://dilbert.com/strip/2008-03-16 If the cost of doing "projects" is low enough, as it is in this case, a completely reasonable response to imprecise specifications is to keep sending the client projects until they tell you what they want. If the client responds to this strategy with verbal abuse, maybe it's time to get new clients.

Comment: @Gaius Oh, I totally agree. It was a pretty poor representation of the company, and the follow up statements that OP mentioned certainly didn't help. Whether the question and it's presentation was scummy or not isn't the point of OP's question. I *think* I understand the rationale of the question, flawed as it was, so I explained what the interviewer's *probably* expected..

Comment: @Acccumulation That sounds like a horrible way to run this business if you want repeat customers.  You seem to have a false dichotomy between just slapping together something that kinda fits, and waiting months to clarify from the client.  It seems like it would be far more professional to just _immediately contact the client to clarify_; especially if it's very easy to get in touch with the client (for example, being right in front of you, having just given you the unclear requirements).  The cost of doing projects is low; but the cost of presenting bad projects to clients may be high.

Comment: @JMac It seems to me that you are the one with a false dichotomy, between contacting the client to clarify, versus presenting them with a project. As I said in my first comment, doing the latter can be an appropriate way of doing the former.

Comment: Who said anything about "slapping together something that kinda fits"? We're talking about presenting them with something that *exactly fits* what they asked for. When a grown-up is presented with something that exactly fits what they asked for, but doesn't fit what they want, their response is not to insult the person that did what they asked, but to realize that they didn't ask properly, and to ask better.

Comment: @Acccumulation But it can also be a terrible way of doing the former, especially in the case where it may seem like you are mocking the request.  It's not necessarily about "turning projects", it's about turning projects that keep you and the client happy.  I'm also not saying that the interviewers responded appropriately to his answer, because insulting people and being rude during an interview is never a good idea from either end.  When a grown up is asked for something, and they don't quite understand it, an adult approach can also be to ask for clarification instead of acting immediately.

Comment: @Acccumulation That's a terrible idea.  All that does is continually reinforce the impression that your company does not deliver what the client wants.  Even if you eventually get it right, you leave them with the experience of you having failed numerous times before finally delivering something satisfactory.  A proactive approach helps you to get it right the first time and to leave a significantly better impression of your business with the client.

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer. A Business Analyst should seek to clarify things they don't understand, not just follow unclear instructions to the letter.

Comment: +1 - it's kind of sad that this isn't the #1 or accepted answer.  The role is for a B.A.  They have to walk into a room with people saying, "We need an inventory tracking system" or something equally vague and have to come up with a set of concrete requirements.  I don't even think the interview question was unfair - they literally gave him a "task" with unclear requirements - as a BA, your instinct *shouldn't* be to just jump and try to do the unclear task.

Comment: The company failed OP, actually. "Are you a robot to follow orders blindly?" What kind of question is that? This company sucks. Good riddance, I say. OP lost nothing and failed nothing. In fact I'd call this a solid win and a bullet well avoided.

Answer (score 23):

I would say this is a relevant question for a business analyst.

Customers/Users will quite often (sic. always) define their requirements incredibly vaguely and it is the job of an analyst to figure out what they **actually want** from what they said.

You should have asked follow up questions such as, write what? How big? In what colour? To show that you have skills in extracting information from people...

Comment: +1 for mentioning additional things such as size and colour. I can now envision half an interview being centered around this one task that results in a very beautifully-written something on the board.

Comment: If you want to go even further and prove you are decent - ask things like 'What are you trying to convey' with the writing, 'What feeling should the writing have' etc. and offer suggestions on how best to accomplish that

Comment: I agree with this entirely. Most likely, they were trying to find out how the OP would react to being given an obviously unclear requirement.

Comment: I wouldn't consider `something` and an unclear requirement, it's less than that. This is not usually what customers would ask for.

Comment: @isaace Hmm you have not met some of the clients I have lol

Comment: I agree. One point I'd add: maybe they don't even know what they want, or [what they claim that they want is totally inappropriate for what they're trying to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). In that case, it's your job to figure out what their actual problem is. If Henry Ford had simply asked people what they want, they would've said "faster horses."

Answer (score 20):

> Is there a better way to handle this?

While the question was vague and weird, writing "something" on the board was certainly not the way to handle it. It is a good prank/joke with your friends but not for an interview. There could be several ways you could have handled it

1. Ask the interviewer politely, what do they want you to write?
2. Write something about the position you were being interviewed for. May be "teach" them a fundamental concept related to FinTech.
3. Write your name/education/experience on the board.

Having said this, I do think it is extremely unusual to ask a candidate to do this without giving more context on why do they want them to do this.

Comment: This reminds me of a viral Indian SWE interview video that was floating around for a while, the end result was that writing *something* on the board **was** the correct answer. It's almost like they watched this video and did the polar opposite.

Comment: @JayGould Interesting. didn't know that. I suppose that is what they want their employees to be good at. Solving stupid word play questions.

Comment: Yup, probably a weird way of finding their critical thinking skills out, or determinng how they handle unclear requirements etc. Found the video here for reference, it went viral on LinkedIn a while ago: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XUhsNIeIgpY

Comment: @JayGould I'd never seen that video before, but now that I've watched it I stand by my answer. That interviewer/organisation would have to offer me something _very_ special to accept any offer they made. He was unprofessional and I wouldn't want to work with him.

Comment: @JayGould I think I understand the point of that video, but it does a remarkably poor job of conveying it. Writing "something" is a complete red herring to their intended message if I'm correct. That said, I agree with Player One. The interviewer acted against the very values he was looking for.

Comment: Whoever made that video, never had to go through an interview to get a job.

Comment: OMG that video is so bad.

Comment: @PagMax yeah it was being praised for being really *creative* and *forward thinking* but it's really backwards.

Answer (score 19):

As a business analyst, one of my biggest jobs is separating the core business need from the person's request. As an example:

Sometimes they're absolutely positive that I need to contract out for ketchup that's sticky enough to adhere to the underside of a hamburger patty, when in fact, I just need to change the burger-creation order so that the bun is added *before* the condiments, and thus provides a surface for said condiments.

So when they told you to write something on the board, you were given a test by a clueless user, and you needed to patiently and diplomatically lead them through the steps to determine what the *real* problem was so that you could solve it. Your immediate solution told them that you either are so literal that you can only follow direct orders (and thus a job like business analyst isn't for you mentally), or that you're a smartass, thus making the user feel stupid and causing them to communicate their issue way less effectively (and thus a job like business analyst isn't for you socially).

Comment: +1 for ketchup example... I might use that one one day

Comment: I totally agree with this - presumably, the last sentence was the reason that they were so annoyed by the response.

Answer (score 13):

You weren't hearing really hearing the intent of question.

Given that the job interview was for a Business Analyst position, I'm assuming that the purpose of asking such an obviously unclear question was to see how you'd handle unclear requests from clients or end users. Given that end users make unclear requests all the time, being able to handle this well is an essential job skill for business analysts.

Presumably, they wanted to see how you would do with pushing back on the request and asking for clarification; however, you didn't push back at all, you got annoyed and just blindly followed the instruction literally.

Think about it from their perspective: is that how you're going to interact with clients and end users? Would *you* hire someone who might handle clients that way? That’s probably why they were annoyed by your response.

That being said, the correct thing to do would have been to ask a clarifying question. If they respond with another vague answer, try going at it from a different angle - e.g. "what problem are you trying to solve?" or "what are you trying to achieve?" or something like that. When - and only when - you thoroughly understand the interviewer's problem should you proceed to write on the board.

Answer (score 8):

> Recently I was in an interview and the very first thing I was asked to do was "write something on the board" and I wrote "something" which they said they found rude.

**If in doubt in an interview setting, clarify requirements. Always.**

> What would you like me to write? My name? "Something" as a literal word? An interesting fact about myself?

I'd imagine at this point they'll clarify.

If they still say "whatever you want", then at that point write "something", a dash, the letter "p", or whatever. If they don't like what you've written at that point, then you're likely better off not working for a company that insists on giving vague requirements while wanting something specific.

Comment: I disagree. If they still say "whatever you want" the OP should press for clarification in a different way - for example, asking them what they're trying to achieve or what problem they're trying to solve. The entire point of the question is to see how the OP would handle someone making an ambiguous, vague, overly broad, incomplete, or otherwise poorly formulated request, so the OP should continue to ask clarifying questions until they understand what the actual need is. Then - and only then - can they write something on the board.

Comment: In fact, if I was the interviewers, I'd reply with an only slightly less vague answer (or some confusing word salad) just to see how the OP would handle someone who doesn't really know what they want. As a business analyst, you *will* encounter this eventually, and it's the business analyst's job to "draw out" what the end user's problem is.

Comment: @EJoshuaS But how far do you take it? 3 times? 5? 10? If you've asked for clarification and the interviewer doesn't give it, it's anyone's guess *what they actually want*. If you keep asking, they could just as easily decide that you're argumentative and will ask too many questions on the job. In all honesty it's a pointless interview question anyway, as your response to superiors asking that in an interview setting is no indication as to whether you'd give that same response to an end user. If I were asked that interview question, it'd certainly go down as a point against the company.

Comment: If you approach it from several different angles and the interviewer still won’t give you anything specific, is have to wonder why they even bothered to ask.

Answer (score 3):

> Recently I was in an interview and the very first thing I was asked to do was "write something on the board" and I wrote "something" which they said they found rude.

I hate these questions which either fall into the category of "do you have an open mind" (too open and the brain falls off), "think out of the box" (no comments) or "let's stress them with a questions somehow related to their job - in that case unclear requirements".

The people who ask these questions like to think of themselves as smart-asses, they lack the smart part.

So. If you are interested in the job, you can give the company some credit and assume that the interviewer is not good. Otherwise just discard the company.

> Is there a better way to handle this?

As for your answer, it was really poor. I am not sure what you wanted to achieve beside trying a kindergarten joke.

I would have asked

- for precisions (if I had no idea what they were talking about)
- or asked whether they have some preferences (if I was suspecting the third case above).

I do not think I would like to work with them anyway.

Comment: For a BA "unclear requirements" shouldn't be a stressor, since it will be part of everyday life.

Comment: @DJClayworth: I know, what I meant was the case of interviewers who, under the pretense of "job related questions", would ask unclear ones for the sake of stressing the candidate. It is different from "as a BA, how would you handle a "write something on board" question from your customers". Everyone know that they are role playing and that's fine.

Answer (score 3):

Unless the interviewer has a really dry sense of humor, they probably won't appreciate this response as they are taking time out of their day to ask you questions to see if you are a good fit for this role.  As Business Analyst, your job (and this is my personal opinion about the role) is to take non-technical requirements from users who don't understand the nuances of software development and feature implementation, and turn them into technical specs that can then be implemented by the developers into a product the company can then sell back to the client or other prospective consumers.

To be a bit more clear, let's take a look at what I think is a great software developer question and how it should be answered.  "Why are manhole covers circular?"  I've discussed this question with a guy who does interviews almost daily and he says he asks that question for two reasons.  1) Given a seemingly trivial or odd question, can you come up with something of substance?  2) What's your problem solving process?

He mentioned that good candidates started immediately throwing out ideas, no matter how silly they may be, and the best candidates would start to think technically about the problem, things like structural integrity of a circle vs a square, cost of material to produce, etc..

If we apply this logic to the statement you were given, I would imagine they wanted you to take an idea and start rolling with it to see where you go.  Maybe you have an idea for a silly invention or website you've been thinking of creating.  I would say it would benefit you greatly to sketch a quick design of that product and start working through the logistics of making it, marketing it, thinking of pitfalls, listing requirements, things like that.

All of this being said, I think asking someone right from the start "Write something on the board" is a bit silly to ask (personal opinion on this, might be a common question in Business Analyst roles).  You'll find there are some interviews where the interviewer simply doesn't do a good job or the company is not a good company to work for and you dodge a bullet by being asked questions like that.  In the future, if you are asked a question like that, just ask for some clarification or start writing stuff on the board that a Business Analyst might record and you should be in the clear.

Answer (score 2):

Some answers have already alluded to the fact that this is likely a specific culture/position test that may indicate the nature of the expected response. That said, I wanted to give an opinion that veers away somewhat.

As a software engineer, instructions should be followed. If there is room for clarification then it should be asked, but when you have an explicit instruction typically you follow it. In your case, I don't see *"write 'something' on the board"* any different than *"show up at 9am for a meeting in room 402"*. Both have a defined goal that can be met - writing, "something" on the board met the requirements. If they wanted something specific, or more general then they should have asked for it. If you want to avoid it in the future, you can always be asking clarification questions but I think this may reflect negatively on your interview if you constantly ask 'obvious' questions.

That said, the moment they followed that up with "*are you a robot to follow orders blindly?*" I would have said I don't waste my time with rude interviewers and walk out. Also in my field, I expect that response to the question would likely be a positive moment rather than a negative (most programmers would get a laugh out of that).

Comment: No, I don't. Clarification should be for filling holes in understanding or comprehension. If I told you to do something, you did it, and then I got mad at you for doing it as I told you - then you would likely be flustered by that chain of events. I do not see any difference here. At worst I don't think it was a winnable situation - ask clarification for an "obvious question" or don't and fail. Both options are bad for you and leave a negative impression.

Comment: Completely agree with this, op hit a bad interview. I've been involved in projects at both ends of the spectrum (not enough and too much attempt at clarification): A 3 turned 18 month project where the 'requirements' from the business folks consisted of a one and a half page document on one end and several simple tasks turned projects turned back to tasks where several rounds of 'clarifying' meetings amounted to a frustrated answer of "yes, it is just as simple as it seems, this was a 10 minute change". Both can look bad.

Comment: @Sh4d0wsPlyr Fortunately or unfortunately, BA and programming require very different skillsets. Think of it as debugging humans until they compile. If they could give you a straight answer outright, there's no need for you there.

Comment: In software engineering, I clarify and question instructions all the time. It's a big part of the job. Example: "when the user taps the input field, the keyboard should open." If I blindly followed that instruction without doing anything else, the keyboard would cover up the input field. Part of my job is recognizing that, clarifying the design, and proposing solutions, not just robotically following the instruction and waiting to be told I've produced something unusable.

Comment: So, as a software developer, if someone said "delete the production database", would you do it? Or would you ask for clarification. That's what this question was about.

Comment: I'm not a fan of ad absurdum arguments. If your developer has direct access to the production database there is already an issue. There is also probably rules and restrictions. However, if the CIO said to delete the prod database, with no background - I expect you would do it too.

Answer (score 2):

When they ask these strangely vague questions it means one of two things:

1. They found something clever online they wanted to use at their interview. This signifies they are inexperienced with job interviewing process. That could be a bad sign that people at the company are overworked, inexperienced at what they do (jack of all trades).
2. It's a common occurance at their company. Someone comes to their company and asks for "something." This could be a sign they're working with hard to understand clients who want "something" but can't explain it. It could also mean a lot of frustration as that "something" might not be what they (clients) want. So it could be a sign of high turn over.

Personally I think you should have asked for clarification. I'm assuming there's no prior comment that you might have missed and they are asking this out of the blue. I would have tried to figure out if it's more of #1 or #2 of the above mentioned items.

Answer (score 1):

There really is no right or wrong answer unless you are trying to blindly get hired at a company which may not be a good fit for you.

It is pretty clear that the company is trying to cultivate a culture of certain personalities.

You could have chosen to write "grass is purple" and if they disagreed then tell them to prove it.

In regards to "are you a robot to follow orders blindly?" you could have suspiciously raised one eyebrow and said:

> Only when I suspect that robot interviewers are asking blind questions.

You could have also chosen to question why are they asking this of you but that could have opened up to other rude questions from the interviewer.

The only person that knows the "correct" response is the interviewer but it's highly unlikely that there is a "correct" response.

Comment: Given they found his actual response rude, your suggested response would have been even ruder. Your formula seems to be a guaranteed way of not getting hired.

Comment: @DJClayworth How you deliver the message is often more important than the message itself

Comment: @MonkeyZeus And you delivery spells an even quicker end of the interview.

Answer (score 0):

> “write something on the board”?

Was this the first question asked to you during the interview? It's an open-ended question, and it could be argued at length if was a good question for an interview.

Disregarding whether the question was bad (or not), writing something *literally* isn't a good idea. At best you can handle such a situation by highlighting any of your skill, accomplishment or knowledge area.

Use it as a starting point for a conversation which you can use to your benefit. Maybe discuss a topic in your domain, a problem area and your take on how it can be better approached.

It's possible to handle such a *bad* question to play to your benefit.

I am taking the positive stand on this and assuming that your interviewer isn't being a jerk, and is just testing how do you handle a situation which you are unprepared for.

Answer (score 0):

**I think you should have answered by writing your name and your short job description.** Maybe some words, why you want to work there, too. Then you should have presented it.

I once had a group interview where we - the interviewed group - were left alone after just a few seconds. We were given a task: after 10 minutes we should present each other. We had boards, cards,.... Therefore I think this was what they would have liked to see. At least we were told the intention.

As it was an interview for training I found this process acceptable. For an experienced worker, IMO, it is childish and therefore rude. It´s some type of an "out of the box" question. IMHO: Some interviewers cover up technical/functional/subject-specific desinformation with such questions.

The boss I left my last job for asked my successor why manhole covers are round.  I never found out any other rational intention. And I would´ve left such an interview, be it rude or not. BTW: I didn´t like to work for that boss.

Comment: “Why are they round?” is a misguided attempt to determine whether the candidate is creative enough to figure out “so they can’t fall into the hole.”  Misguided, because chances are anyone over 25 has already heard the riddle.

Comment: “Because they can’t fall into the hole” has two problems. One, there are other shapes that can’t fall into a hole of the same shape. Two, there are other reasons. A round hole is much easier to create, if the hole is within a concrete tube, a round shape withstands stress better, and one man can move a round cover effortlessly by rolling it.

Comment: PS. Followup question: Why are my stop cock covers square and not round?

Answer (score 0):

As you say you are applied for the post of Business Analyst. Obviously,you go through company's profile and the work they are doing. so in my opinion you have to write something wise that matches to companies expectation for your post according to their business.
 Ex, If company is working in Material Science Firm then you can write 'graphene' as it is future of Materials as per current research. These type of answer shows both your analysis/research power and company's profitability.
I hope this will help you.